# Call a local function inside if Statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No argument supplied"
    exit
fi

if [ "$1"="abc" ] ; then
abc
exit
fi

if [ "$1" = "def" ]; then
def
exit 1
fi

function abc()
{
    echo "hello"
}

function def()
{
    echo "hi"
}
```

Here abc is a function which has local definition. But Bash is giving error "./xyz.sh: line 10: abc: command not found". Please give me any Solution?

Comment: Show the whole script, or at least the function definition relative to your if statement.

Comment: The function needs to be declared before the code you are executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions must be declared before they can be used, so move your declarations to the top.

Also, you need to have a space on either side of the `=` in your string comparison test.

The following script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

function abc()
{
    echo "hello"
}

function def()
{
    echo "hi"
}

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No argument supplied"
    exit
fi

if [ "$1" = "abc" ] ; then
   abc
   exit
fi

if [ "$1" = "def" ]; then
   def
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It would be somewhat more succinct and idiomatic to do the conditional as a `case` statement, by the way.  `case $1 in abc) abc; exit;; def) def; exit 1;; esac`

Comment: And your error message should look like `echo "$0: No argument supplied" >&2` with the script name in the message and the redirect to standard error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a problem with your declaration of abc.  If you provide the code for your script, we'll be more able to provide specific help, but here is an example of what I think you are trying to achive.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

abc(){
  echo "ABC. bam!"
}

foo="bar"
if [ "$foo"="bar" ]; then
  abc
else
 echo "No bar for you"
fi
```